# Set attribute to dynamically generated <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

I am adding dynamic row to table through JavaScript:

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

var element2 = document.createElement('input');    
element2.value = "valueHere";
element2.type = "text";

cell1.appendChild(element2);
```

It creates new row in table:

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <input type="text" value="valueHere">
 </td>
</tr>
```

I want to add a class to `<td>` tag. e.g. `<td class="styleClass">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a class to a cell/TD

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.className = 'styleClass';
    //cell1.style = ... whatever you want
...
rest of your code
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.className) property of the table cell (`cell1`):

```
cell1.className = 'styleClass';
```